# How do I include a composer package into plain php?

Tags: php, composer-php

Good afternoon, I will start off by saying that I've never included a composer project in my projects unless it was a composer package for the Laravel framework. Where you "require" it and add it to the providers array and aliases if needed.

Now, the problem. I have a composer package I'm trying to play around with https://github.com/WHAnonymous/Chat-API the problem is i dont know how to include it into myu project since its not really made "for" laravel. So I'm trying to use plain php without a framework but I have no idea how to "load" the package in, tried googling and only found information regarding building a package.

To clarify: I can install the package fine, its the php part of "loading" the package in my index.php file that im struggling with, pretend the index.php file is empty.

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

After installing the package with composer, the composer has generated an autoloader that you can include with:

```
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
```

Then you can use the classes of the package without further includes. In your example this might be:

```
// Create an instance of WhatsProt.
$w = new WhatsProt($username, $nickname, $debug);
```

(taken from https://github.com/WHAnonymous/Chat-API/blob/master/examples/exampleRegister.php)

Note that this line from the example is ***not*** necessary, when you use the composer autoloader:

```
require_once('../src/whatsprot.class.php');
```

Comment: Updating on this, autoload.php is now directly under `/vendor` directory. So, `require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';`

Comment: From what I understand, there is little reason not to use autoloading - however, I'd still be interested in what the "native" way to include files/classes/... from composer packages would be.

Answer (score -3):

Assuming you have composer installed and have gone through the basics in the link posted by Paul.

You would run the following

```
~/composer install (same directory your composer.json file resides in).
```

Contents of composer.json file would be:

```
{
    "require" : {
        "whatsapp/chat-api" : "2.5.4"
    }
}
```

Comment: yes this i understand very well, but in PHP, when I need to use it, how do "load" the package in?